# Directory protection asking for password twice on my https website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, password-protection

I am trying to protect my website with a directory protection code. The website is in PHP.

My website has https and it is like https://www.example.com.

When I Open the website it is asking for username and password twice. I think it is taking once for http and once for https.

Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem.

Below is my `.htaccess file code`

```
options -multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "example.com"
AuthUserFile /www.example.com/web/content/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 
   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting authentication dialogue twice because Apache runs `mod_auth` directive before `mod_rewrite` directive. Also `authentication` session set in HTTP URL isn't valid in HTTPS URL anymore therefore it Apache has to follow the BASIC auth directive under HTTPS as well.

There can be some `work-around` type solutions to skip BASIC auth for http URL and do it only for HTTPS but it is not straight forward.

#### UPDATE: Here is a workaround solution that you can use to avoid showing BASIC auth dialogue twice.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# redirect to HTTPS and set a cookie NO_AUTH=1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,CO=NO_AUTH:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# If cookie name NO_AUTH is set then set env variable SHOW_AUTH
SetEnvIfNoCase COOKIE NO_AUTH=1 SHOW_AUTH

# show Basic auth dialogue only when SHOW_AUTH is set
AuthType Basic
AuthName "example.com"
AuthUserFile /www.example.com/web/content/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=SHOW_AUTH
Satisfy any
```

Since cookie is only set for `http://domain.com` therefore env variable is also set only once and **BASIC auth dialog is also shown only once**.

Comment: Could you tell me any way of doing it?

Comment: It won't be a straight forward way to do it. I will provide an answer.

Comment: May I know your Apache version?